# Question about integrable functions

Tags: analysis

Is it true that if $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is integrable on a measure space $(X, M, \mu)$ then for arbitrary $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a set $A \in M$ with finite measure such that $\int_{X\setminus A} |f| d \mu <\varepsilon$?

Edit.

Thanks for help. If I understood correctly, for each $n \in \mathbb N$ the set $A_n:=\{x\in X: |f(x)|>\frac{1}{n} \}$ is of finite measure, the sequence  $(X\setminus A_n)$ is decreasing, its intersection is equal $\{x: f(x)=0\}$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{X\setminus A_n} |f| d \mu=
 \int_{ \bigcap_{n\in N}(X \setminus  A_n) } |f| d \mu=
 \int_{ \{x: f(x)=0 \} } |f| d \mu=0$.
 Hence for given  $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $m\in N$ such that $\int_{X\setminus A_m} |f| d\mu < \varepsilon$, and $\mu(A_m)<\infty$.

Comment: I would only add that to make the limit work you want the Lebesgue Dominated (or Monotone) Convergence Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let $A_n = \{x: |f(x)| > 1/n\}$.